# How to set 4 button in centerHorizontal in Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, button, layout

I want to set 4 button in center Horizontal in a Layout...
Like that
Here is my screenshot!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/td9r52pagi9kwco/qs.png

Comment: Have you tried any thing or you need a programmer to do?

Answer (score 4):

This works for you :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this one...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relative_1"
    android:text="3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
    android:text="2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:text="4" />
```

Answer (score 2):

wrap all `Button` in `LinearLayout` and put `LinearLayout` in `RelativeLayout` if you really wish to use `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, please mention your parent `Layout` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Button3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Button4" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_1"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_2"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_3"
            android:text="4" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

From my ans i am getting screen like this.

[image]

For OP's question my ans is correct. can any one tell me what's wrong in my ans. the downvoter need to tell why do you downvote

Comment: `RelativeLayout` is heavy compared to `LinearLayout`. So, our first preference should be to use `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @Manjunath Not that much of *heavy*

Comment: We can notice the heaviness of `RelativeLayout`, if we make a `ViewPager`'s page as `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @Manjunath There is no heavy work in this alignment.

Comment: Sir, I am not telling this is heavy. But, use of `LinearLayout` makes it lighter.

Comment: @Manjunath what's wrong in my ans why did you put downvote . Is this not a right answer?

Comment: For OP's question my ans is correct. can any one tell me what's wrong in my ans. the downvoter need to tell why do you downvote

Comment: android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_1" or android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_1"?

Comment: @jsanmarb after saving your layout you can remove + from `@+id`. For designing pupose i added +. Otherwise you cannot see correct design in  graphical layout